# way of communicating between Windows phone app and desktop app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want my windows phone app to communicate with a desktop app (in Windows), basically i want to send a picture which is captured in the phone to be send to the desktop app and get back the feedback from the desktop app.

Whats the most elegant and modular and simple way of doing this?

Comment: Upload your image to a cloud type service (Dropbox, etc) then run a desktop app/silverlight that retrieves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can force your user to connect via wifi such that he is on the same local network as the desktop, you listen for the phone's connection on a higher port and transfer the data to/from it over TCP directly.

Otherwise, the best way to do this at present would be via the internet, using your server to synchronize files and messages between the two devices.